# Marker Label not showing - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with `Google API v3` and also utilizing `MarkerwithLabel`.  The problem I am having even after including the `Google API v3` lib and `MarkerwithLabel` lib.  My label never displays on the map.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=.......v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script><!-- Very Important For Google Maps-->

<script src="js/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
```

Now after I am running the test example they give:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
     var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-cont'), {
       zoom: 12,
       center: latLng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
       position: homeLatLng,
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true,
       map: map,
       labelContent: "$425K",
       labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
       labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
       labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
     });

     var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: "Home For Sale"
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });
```

Now after running this, I never see a label.

Suggestions?

Comment: try the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add styles to your labels with CSS .try using this:

```js
function initialize() {
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-cont'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: latLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: homeLatLng,
  draggable: true,
  raiseOnDrag: true,
  map: map,
  labelContent: "$425K",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
  labelClass: "labels", // try adding css as below
  labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
  optimized:false
});

var iw1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "Home For Sale"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, "click", function (e) { iw1.open(map, this); });  
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.labels {
     color: red;
     background-color: white;
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     width: 40px;
     height:20px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/src/markerwithlabel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map-cont" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Posting code without an explanation of what you did/tried to fix the issue is not useful to OP and others who read this post.

Comment: @MrUpsidown can't you run the code snippet and see.OP asked for label which you can see in the answer.

Comment: why this down-vote just run the code and see for once it is working fine.

Comment: This worked great, was the only reasoning because of the css?

Comment: Reason is: read above comment. OP doesn't know what fixed the issue. Explain your answers. It's always better. Don't just say: here is the code, it works, use it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown it was css issue and i added that in my code by running it you can see the output that is what i meant.

Comment: Then a very simple phrase like *You need to add styles to your labels with CSS* would be enough. Of course we see that it works. Just explain why it does.

Comment: @MrUpsidown got it thanks for your time anyways.if possible remove your down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

If it's help to others, my situation was that I was displaying an integer as the label. Needed to call `toString()` on it:

```
new maps.Marker({
    ...
    label: location.label == null ? null : location.label.toString(),
    ...
})
```

For some reason, it took me a bit to see google's error message about it in the console: "InvalidValueError: setLabel: not a string; and no text property"